# Is there any way to cast from Field to an Object?

Tags: java, reflection

So I need a way to check for the existence of an annotation on a field and if the annotation does exist, to cast that field to its actual type so I can access its methods. That might not make much sense so in code this is roughly what I'd like to be able to do.

There's a class that looks something like this:

```
class A 
{
  @CustomAnnotation
  public ServerA server = new ServerA();

  ...
}
```

And in another class I want to run through Class's A fields and check for the existence of the annotation and then perform some actions if it does

```java
class Z 
{
  public void deleteFilesIfAnnotationExists()
  {
    Field[] fields = class.forName(A.class);
    for(Field field : fields)
    {
      if((field.getAnnotation(CustomAnnotation.class))!=null)
      {

        //the following code is wishful thinking
        if(field instanceof ServerA)
        {
          ServerA server = (ServerA) field; //what i really need to be able to do
          server.deleteFilesFromServerRootDir();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there anyway to do something similar to this or is it just wishful thinking? From the javadoc for `Field` it didn't seem obvious if it was.

Comment: You have an **instance** field, where's your **instance**?

Comment: Read the javadoc of `Field#get(Object)`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Right, but with `Field#get(Object)` I need a reference to the actual instance of `ServerA` called `server` right? However in reality, `class Z` is used on a ton of classes other than `class A` where the field names might be different. So I need a generic way to cast fields of class to their "actual type"

Comment: No. With `get`, you need an instance of type `A`. It's that instance field's value you're getting back. That value is returned as an `Object`. You can then cast it to whatever type you want, `ServerA` in this case.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Ahh I understand now, the javadoc confused me as to what type of object it was expecting. Do you want to phrase it as an answer and I'll give you the approved answer mark?

Comment: There's no need. You have your solution.